# Not getting 1 when casting to bool

Tags: c++, casting, boolean

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(void* buffer) {
    int x = static_cast<bool>(*(char*)buffer);
    int y = static_cast<bool>(*(bool*)buffer);
    std::cout << x << " " << y;
}

int main() {
    int a = 255;
    f(&a);
}
```

On GCC 9.1, I'm getting the following output:

> 1 255

Why the cast to `bool` with `(char*)` cast results `x` to be 1 and the cast to `bool` with `(bool*)` cast results `y` to be, in this case, 255?

Comment: `(bool*)buffer` is undefined behavior. There is no `bool` at the address `buffer` points to, so you lied to your type system.

Comment: A cast from bool to bool is a no-op. The compiler generates no machine code for it. Did you expect any other kind of real-world result from this program? (Theoretically it could be anything of course because it's UB).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the cast to bool ... with (bool*) cast results ...?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Standard says (quoting the latest draft):

> [basic.lval]
>
> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar ([conv.qual]) to one of the following types **the behavior is undefined**:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

`bool` is not similar to dynamic type of `buffer`, it is neither `unsigned` nor `unsigned` corresponding type, nor is it `char` `unsigned char`, or `std::byte`. Therefore behaviour is undefined.

> Why the cast to bool with (char*) cast results x to be 1

Because the first byte of `a` contained a value that did not represent a zero. Whether this will be the case depends on the CPU architecture. The order of bytes of an integer is implementation defined.

Note that the behaviour would be well defined in this case, because `char` is listed as one of the exceptions in the quoted rule.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `reinterpret_cast<int *>`. For example

```
int y = static_cast<bool>(*reinterpret_cast<int*>( buffer ));
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 255;
    void *buffer = &x;
    int y = static_cast<bool>(*reinterpret_cast<int*>( buffer ));

    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The key here is not the use of `reinterpret_cast` but the fact that the cast is to the correct type (either pointer to the type of the object living there or `char*`).

Comment: Why not `static_cast` the void pointer? Is implicit conversion to `void*`, then `reinterpret_cast` back guaranteed to be the same? I know it is guaranteed in case of `static_cast`.

Comment: @eerorika It may be used but with pointers I prefer to use reinterpret cast. It is important to cast to int *.